# On the inner surface of the cone of the figure

Tags: geometry

On the inner surface of the cone of the figure, a small object of mass $m$ is thrown horizontally, with speed $v_{o}$. Determine at what height $h$ on the vertex of the cone the object has to be thrown so that it does not go down nor rise by the plane of the cone (it moves in the horizontal plane). Neglect friction; $H = 40 [cm]$, $R = 20 [cm]$ and $v_{o} = 1.2 [m / s]$.

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a free-body diagram of the forces acting on the ball? For the ball to neither accelerate up nor down, the forces in the vertical direction must sum to 0.

Comment: If the statement asks for an equation in which the ball always in the same plane, it thinks that it should have no variation in $y$ that the equation depends only on $x$. If it describes a perfect circular path, it must be the equation of a uniform circular motion because it is uniformly accelerated circular motion, it will rise or fall on the surface of the cone. @Samadin

Comment: I think the question is simply asking the value of $h$ where the force of gravity cancels out the vertical component of the normal force on the ball. The normal force will vary with $h$, as angular velocity varies with $h$. @b582941

Comment: this Wikipedia article on [banked turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banked_turn) should help.